# How to return a global variable value from inside a function in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following:

```
 $(document).ready ->
    root = exports ? this
    root.hello = -> 'hello world'
    world = ->
        root.hello
    alert world
```

The alert message pops up:

```
function() {
       root.hello }
```

I want it to popup "hello world".  How do I return coffeescript global variables from within a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you have to do:

First, remove the `->` in

```
root.hello = -> 'hello world'
//           ^^ remove this
```

That `->` means you're assigning a *function* to `root.hello`.

Then, you need to add `()` after `world` when doing the call, so you're *calling* `world`, not just referring to it.

```
alert world()
//         ^^ Add these
```

So:

```
$(document).ready ->
    root = exports ? this
    root.hello = 'hello world'
    world = ->
        root.hello
    alert world()
```

Comment: Hi, I updated the question above to reflect your comment, removing the "->" still presents the same issue.

Comment: @Bruce: Don't update questions to incorporate answers, it messes up the question for people in the future. If your original code had the `->`, put it back in the question. I found a second problem, and updated the answer. *Edit*: I've restored the code in the question.

Comment: Thank you TJ, for the answer and the tip about questions.